# Nginx 1.10.3: Alternative to upstream server max_conns

Tags: nginx, debian, debian-jessie, debian-stretch

I've got a server running open source `Nginx 1.10.3` with a pretty simple config: Serving static files, in case a file doesn't exist, the request is send to a backend.

I need to limit the active connections to this backend. Quite easy, isn't it, using `upstream server max_conns`, which

> limits the maximum number of simultaneous active connections to the proxied server.

Besides, this was only introduced in `1.11.5`, so it's not (yet) available for me.

Any clever ideas / workarounds out there dealing with this situation?

[This server is currently running `Debian jessie` with `nginx` out of `jessie-backports`. I *could* upgrade to `stretch`, and use `stretch-backports`. But, before doing so, and because I'm quite happy with this system, I would like to check if there is any other way around. You know: Never change a running system...]

Comment: You can try to find another repository which has a newer version of nginx available for Jessie.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Thanks, but I don't use third party repos on production machines, so that's no alternative.